# printf() function causes segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

This code when compiled allows me to connect to a server using a correct IP address as the program parameter. So far, the connection is fine and data is sent to the server, but when I attempt to use the recv() function to try to collect data in non-blocking mode, I receive a segmentation fault. It always appears after the "receiving data..." line.

As you can see, I reserved 5000 bytes of stack memory for the operation and I'm testing with trying to read only one byte without success. Does recv() not work with stack memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern errno;

struct sockaddr_in a;
struct timeval tv;
fd_set wready;

long conntoserver(const char* ip,const char* data){
    memset((char*)&a,0,sizeof(a));
    if (inet_aton(ip,a.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0){printf("Can't set address\n");return -1;}
    long s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);if (s < 0){printf("Can't make socket\n");return -1;}
    tv.tv_sec=1;tv.tv_usec=0;FD_ZERO(&wready);FD_SET(s,&wready);
            //start non-blocking mode
    if (fcntl(s,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK) < 0){printf("Can't make socket non-blocking\n");close(s);return -1;}
    a.sin_family=AF_INET;a.sin_port=htons(80);long ret=connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&a,sizeof(a));
    if (ret < 0 && errno != EINPROGRESS){printf("Can't connect to IP. %s\n",strerror(errno));close(s);return -1;}
    if (errno == EINPROGRESS){
    printf("connection in progress...\n");
    ret=select(s+1,NULL,&wready,NULL,&tv);
    if (ret < 0){printf("select() error. %s\n",strerror(errno));close(s);return -1;}
    if (ret==0){printf("select() timeout. %s\n",strerror(errno));close(s);return -1;}
    }
    unsigned long sz=strlen(data);
    ssize_t ns=send(s,data,sz,0);
    if (ns==sz){return s;}else{return -1;}
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if (argc < 2){printf("Format: %s < IP to connect to >\n",argv[0]);return -1;}
    long s=conntoserver(argv[1],"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: example.com\n\n");
    if (s < 0){printf("Error making server request. %s\n",strerror(errno));close(s);return -1;}
    printf("receiving data...\n");
    char b[5001];
    ssize_t br=recv(s,b,1,0);
    printf("br=%s\n",br);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("br=%s\n",br);
```

Should be:

```
printf("br=%ld\n",br);
```

BTW -- I had to fix a number of problems to make this code compile. You should always pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: My compiler must be old then because I received no warning, but that change does work

Comment: @Mike The compiler can't give warnings about semantic errors in string literals supplied as arguments.

Comment: @EJP I'm running GCC 4.2.1, and it can indeed warn about printf format inconsistencies (with -Wformat is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the error pointed out by @keithmo, you have an error here:

```
    if (inet_aton(ip,a.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0){printf("Can't set address\n");return -1;}
```

The second argument to `inet_aton()` is expected to be a *pointer* to a `struct in_addr` but you are passing a value of type `uint32_t`.  In fact, that value is initialized to zero, so the result is likely (but not certain) to be equivalent to passing a `NULL` pointer.  Either way, this produces undefined behavior, and I'd surprised if that didn't manifest as a segfault.  Even if the program runs past that, the call as you wrote it cannot produce the (apparently) desired effect of initializing the address in variable `a`.

What you want instead is

```
    if (inet_aton(ip, &a.sin_addr) == 0) {
        printf("Can't set address\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

And for goodness's sake, *do* make free with the spaces and newlines.  They greatly improve code legibility.  If you're short, I can lend you some.